# Grails db migration not being applied

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am using Grails 2.4.3 and the database-migration:1.4.0 plugin.

I have created a simple Domain class called Mod. I am able to create the groovy based changelog using `dbm-generate-gorm-changelog changelog.groovy`. This correctly generates the file. I then execute `dbm-update` which reports:

```
|Starting dbm-update for database sa @ jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000
|Finished dbm-update
```

However, there are no table created in the database and running `dvm-status` returns:

```
|Starting dbm-status for database sa @ jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
1 change sets have not been applied to SA@jdbc:h2:mem:devDb
     changelog.groovy::1413897188349-1::clarkrichey (generated)
|Finished dbm-status
```

My development environment configuration from DataSource.groovy is as follows:

```
 development {
        dataSource {
//            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue centers around the fact you are using an in-memory instance of h2. Thus, nothing is saved between application launches. If you want a persistent database then change your url to use a file based instance.

```
development {
  dataSource {
    dbCreate = "none" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
    url = "jdbc:h2:file:/path/to/save/to/devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
  }
}
```

Comment: OK. So I tried this url: jdbc:h2:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
which, according to http://h2database.com/html/cheatSheet.html should create the devDb in the working directory. However, the dvm-update command just hangs on starting dbm-update

Comment: OK. I had to manually delete the lock file and now it works. Thanks!